# Why is my SQL inside of Access VBA Selecting Gobbledygook?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

This is my code.  It should be returning NX as a 5 digit number that is sequentially one more than the previous 5 digit number.  ie: 118-31234 should return 118-31235.  Instead, my query is returning 118-99993.

My table has certain things that might be playing tricks on my query. For example, 118-9999A-01-PVH is one of the entries in my table.  My hypothesis is that 118-9999A-01-PVH is making my query return 118-99993.

Would someone help me bug test this code to see why it is returning 118-99993 when it should be returning 118-31235, please?  Thank you!

```
    SQL = "SELECT Table01.Code01, Left([Code01],(InStr([Code01],""-"")-1)) AS CatC, Mid([Code01],(InStr([Code01],""-"")+1),5) AS Seq INTO TempC1 " & _
                "FROM Table01 WHERE (((Left([Code01],(InStr([Code01],""-"")-1)))=GetCX()) AND ((Mid([Code01],(InStr([Code01],""-"")+1),5)) Not Like ""*[!0-9]*"") " & _
                "AND ((Len(Mid([Code01],(InStr([Code01],""-"")+1),5)))=5) AND ((InStr([Code01],""-""))=4)) " & _
                "ORDER BY Mid([Code01],(InStr([Code01],""-"")+1),5); "
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    If DCount("[Seq]", "TempC1") = 0 Then
        NX = "30000"
        Else: NX = DMax("[Seq]", "TempC1")
    End If

    Me.Seq.Value = NX + 1
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "TempC1"
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue using the two sample values you specified. However, the fact that you're getting `99993` suggests that there is a value that contains the string `99992`. Is that the case?

Comment: I know.  It's infuriating.  I can't reproduce the error, either.  To me, it looks like the SQL is fine.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the way Access Jet converts SQL  No. There is nothing in the database containing 99992.